# Firebase, trying to pull the collection based on a ID?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Basically, I have two collections per post. One with the comments on the post and one with the post information. The formula I wrote gives me the data of the post information. I want it to return both collections so I can map through the comment collection. but I cannot seem to figure out how to get it to send me to one level up basically. Any help would be appreicated!

```
const docRef = doc(db, "posts", postId);
```

useEffect(() => {

```
if(postId){
  const getUsers = async () => {
    const data = await getDoc(docRef)
    console.log(data.data())
  }
  getUsers()
}
```

}, [])

[image: Comments and Structure]

[image: item]

The answer I was looking for is as follows!

```
    const stepOne = collection(db,"posts")
    const stepTwo = doc(stepOne,postId)
    const stepThree = collection(stepTwo,"comments")
    const stepFour = onSnapshot(stepThree,((snapshot)=>snapshot.docs.map((doc)=>console.log(doc.data()))))
```

Comment: It's not clear to me what you mean by "*I cannot seem to figure out how to get it to send me to one level up basically*".  Could you describe in more detail what is the part that you're stuck on?  If you want data from two collections, you'll need to do two queries.  They can't be combined into a single query.

Comment: So basically, how I have it set up. Each post has two things the post detail and a nested collection of comments. Each comment will have a name and text. the getDoc(docRef) is only logging the post details. I thought it would also log the collection as they have the same postID because the collection of comments is nested in the post. I feel like this is impossible. I am thinking I should switch it the comments to an array of objects in the post collection. that way I at least have access to it so I can map through it. thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Through this structure on the picture, comments are a collection nested inside posts, right? If so, then you cannot return a subcollection from a simple query on the parent document. Try fetching the post info first, then fetch the comments from an other query

this is for posts:

```
const docRef = doc(db, "posts", postId);
```

the path for comment will be

```
"posts/postId/comment"
```

Comment: I would need the commentID in this situation correct? so it would be like commentRef = doc(db,`/posts/${postId}/comments`,commentID)  is there a way I can get the collection without the commentID

Comment: Thank you by the grace himself, It works. Wow that was an experience